# How can I easily specify an or-search in Finder?

Tags: macos, finder

I wanted to create a smart-search for my R-files, including both files ending in ".r" and ".rmd". Obviously, files can't end in both.

This yields only files that satisfy both criteria
[image: entering both endings into the search box]

This yields no files because the criteria are mutually exclusive.
[image: adding another search-option via the plus-button]

How can I search for files ending in either .r or .rmd and more generally
how can I specify "or"-searches/ disjunctions? Using "or" or "||" didn't do the trick.

Comment: Can't test this right now, but will the field accept a *list*, i.e. Can you put multiple extensions into that first textbox, separated with a comma, or something?

Comment: @Dan No success with that either.

Answer (score 1):

Operands must be written in capitals, so they are understood as such. Therefore, using **OR** instead of **or**, will do exactly what you want.

Comment: No, [it doesn't](http://imgur.com/n2Wth). The "OR" operator works when I'm using plain search terms (i.e. searching file names and contents), but not when the OR is between two blue boxes or in a blue box or in the search bar field "Name ends with".

Comment: @Ruben But you can use, in this case, `.r OR .rmd` and it will work.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Do I need to show you proof? ;-) That gives me .rdata,.rdb,.rdx files too, and it does a content-search. I could use all kinds of exclusionary criteria now, but that's annoying and not future-proof.

Comment: @Ruben For the Content-Search, you are right. Try this `".r" OR ".rmd"`, though.

Comment: That does in fact narrow it down although it still yields .rdata files. It is apparently possible to get the blue "in file name" box to interpret quot. marks, the [outer quot. marks are then omitted](http://imgur.com/5gHAY) and they also work in "File name matches" as bar, but not in "ends with". Still, problem not solved, because I'd have to exclude all the extraneous hits by specifying them.

Comment: But why are you doing the *blue box* thingy? Why not do it like [this](http://imgur.com/yZdpR). Despite having to handle the *content-search* it does exactly what you want.

Comment: Well, because I'd have to handle the Content-search. But I'm giving up on this now, it's not important enough for such a long process.